# HoughLinesP: lines don't reach border

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get lines from images that contain some harder lines and a few very clear ones. My problem is that very often my returned lines, even for the super-clear cases, don't reach the borders of the frame. I have tried using `HoughLinesP` after `Canny` (as customary) and also (with better results) after getting the "skeleton" of the image, as seen [in this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLE1U.png) which provides [this source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MASAS.png).

My code is like everyone else's (this is a matter of either understanding the parameters better or getting some new insight). Case with `Canny`:

```py
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
    edges,
    rho=1,
    theta=np.pi / 180,
    threshold=90,
    minLineLength=200,
    maxLineGap=100,
)
```

Of course I have tried many different parameters, but I honestly don't know which one should be related to this.

Here are some pictures as example.

Original image:

[image: original image showing two clear lines]

Using the code as shown (`Canny` + `HoughLinesP`):

[image: lines from Canny and HoughLinesP stop well before the frame edges]

If I first add an artificial white border the results improve, but not quite solve it:

[image: adding a white border before finding lines does not solve the problem]

Getting the skeleton of the image before `HoughLinesP` (instead of `Canny`) is better, but has the same problem. First with the original image:

[image: using the image skeleton instead of Canny does not solve the problem]

Using skeletons + extra border before lines is not enough either:

[image: skeleton then HoughLinesP does not get complete lines even using a white frame]

Comment: Images you shared is complicated. Can you explain the images you shared clearly? Cos I couldnt connect images between each other

Comment: The first one is the source image, from which I want to extract lines. The others are the results of applying HoughLinesP (first two after Canny, last two after getting the skeleton of the original image). In images 3 and 5 I have also added a white border to the original image before getting lines.

Comment: How can you get those outputs from that source image ? Where those different lines coming from ? What cauisng to appear them ?

Comment: The stray lines on the left and at the top part of the image are not important. Those happen because I am not showing a bit of the original image for privacy reasons.

Comment: I am doing some tests and I may have removed too much from you, surprisingly it does affect (the problem persists, though). So I am preparing an update on the question with uncensored images.

Comment: Done, I have uploaded new images. Now they are exactly as I used them, same size and all.